# How to fix "ErrorException' in blade in laravel-5.3

Tags: laravel-5

```
<a href="{{route('frontend.subscribe.index'),[$plan->plan_id]}}" class="btn btn-success">purchase</a>
```

this is my problem to send plan object argument to `frontend.subscribe.index`

> `ErrorException in UrlGenerationException.php line 17:
>   Missing required parameters for [Route: frontend.subscribe.index] [URI: subscribe/{plan_id}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\larafiles\resources\views\frontend\plans\index.blade.php)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing the `route` function too early. Move the closing bracket to the end:

```
{{ route('frontend.subscribe.index', [$plan->plan_id]) }}
```